# Garbage Collection issue with infinite ImageViews

Tags: java, android-studio, garbage-collection, imageview, infinite-loop

My code is creating ImageViews (image of a target) at a set rate that are displayed on the UI and will be removed from the main layout after 3 seconds or once it has been clicked on. The problem is the garbage collection causes delay when I create these ImageViews, which delays the creation of further ImageViews

Here I spawn call for the ImageView to be created in a while loop:

```
//for each multiple of the spawn rate value, a target will be spawned
                    while (currentTimeOfGame % spawnRate == 0) {
                        createTarget(context);
                        //update the time of game relative to the game's start time
                        currentTimeOfGame = ((new Date().getTime()) - startTime);
                    }
```

And then in createTarget() I create an instance of the Target class which extends ImageView.

```
    //method for creating the targets
    public void createTarget(Context context) {
        //dimensions of the main relative layout
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        //instantiate a target to spawn
        final Target target = new Target(context);
        target.setParams(width, height);
```

Here it is removed from the layout once it is clicked. This removes the targets fine but after a few of them, it causes delays caused by the garbage collector, which only delays the next spawn.

```
        Runnable thread = () -> target.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Handler subMainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
            Runnable subThread = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    target.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    removeView(target);
                    target.setImageDrawable(null);
//            Log.d("target clicked", String.valueOf(currentTimeOfGame));
//            Interrupting the thread that tracks the target's timer
                    spawnTarget.interrupt();
                }
            };
            subMainHandler.post(subThread);

        });
```

This is the class for the Target.

```
public class Target extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView {

    public long spawnTime = new Date().getTime();

    public Target(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.target_shape);
        this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void setParams(int width, int height) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Random r = new Random();

        this.setLayoutParams(params);
        int randomLeftMargin = r.nextInt(width);
        int randomTopMargin = r.nextInt(height);
        params.leftMargin = randomLeftMargin;
        params.topMargin = randomTopMargin;
        this.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

}
```

This is the XML file of the target

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/PrimaryBlue" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/LightGrey" />
    <size
        android:width="30dp"
        android:height="30dp" />
</shape>
```

How do I prevent the garbage collector from causing delays up to 300 milliseconds? Is this to do with creating a new instance of the Target class every time I create a new Target?

EDIT:

Code for handling the 3 second timer for each targets life span. a target is removed whenever a target isn't clicked within 3 seconds, after 3 seconds. a life is deducted each time, and once there are 0 lives, no more targets are spawned. The issue with the delay is caused by this block of code where the player still has lives and the target is removed with a click, so this thread is interrupted by the onClickListener.

```
       Thread handleTarget = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                //updating the location of the target to ensure it doesn't overlap with the edge
                Runnable setTargetParamsThread = () -> {
                    int targetWidth = target.getMeasuredWidth();
                    int targetHeight = target.getMeasuredHeight();
                    if (targetHeight != 0 && targetWidth != 0) {
                        target.setParams(width, height, targetWidth, targetHeight);
                        target.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                };
                mainHandler.post(setTargetParamsThread);


                while (true) {
                    //check if the target has reached 3 seconds without being tapped
                    if (new Date().getTime() > target.spawnTime + 3000) {

                        if (lives == 0) {
                            gameOver = true;
                            //discontinue of the number of lives = 0 as the game is over
                            target.setClickable(false);

                            //fade out animation for target on end of game for remaining targets
                            Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
                            fadeOut.setDuration(250);
                            AnimationSet animFadeOut = new AnimationSet(true);
                            animFadeOut.addAnimation(fadeOut);
                            target.setAnimation(animFadeOut);

                            Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
                            Runnable thread = () -> removeView(target);
                            mainHandler.post(thread);

                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        }

                        //if the target is visible remove it and deduct a life.
                        else if (target.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                            //remove the target and deduct a life
                            target.setImageDrawable(null);
                            Handler mainHandler2 = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
                            Runnable thread = () -> removeView(target);
                            mainHandler2.post(thread);

//                            Log.d("target removed", String.valueOf(currentTimeOfGame));
                            lives--;
//                            Log.v("lives", String.valueOf(gameOver));
                            //discontinue the thread for this target once it has been removed as it no longer needs to be referenced
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Why are you suddenly using an anonymous inner class within the nested lambda expressions? Inner classes keep a hidden reference to their outer object, even if never used. Might not be the cause of your problems, but surely doesn’t improve the situation. And well, I bet, Android has a builtin solution for changing images that does not require dealing with threads manually.

Comment: @Holger I needed to because this all runs in a thread, and I can't touch these views from within the thread without nesting lambda expressions. I've since found that the problem is the delay is caused when the view is removed from the 3 second timer but I'm not entirely sure why. I've added this code to the original post.

Comment: I didn’t ask why you are using lambda expressions, I asked why you are suddenly using *an anonymous inner class* for implementing a `Runnable`, instead of another lambda expression. Inside two nested lambda expressions which show that you know the concept of lambda expressions. But when you say you have issues with garbage collection performance, why do you keep using constructs like `new Date().getTime()` which gives you nothing else than `System.currentTimeMillis()`, except also creating garbage?

Comment: And what do you think, will `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` do inside a piece of code that clearly never checks its own interruption status? Surely not ending your `while(true)` loop.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the pointers, I've resolved the problem now. I'm quite new to Java + Android Studio so there were some things I wasn't sure of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing anonymous inner classes and handling Thread interruptions resolved the issue.